# CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC on ARM Linux kernel?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm

I can not find any patch of CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC for ARM architecture.
I am just curious to ask few questions.
1)Is it not implemented for ARM so far ?
2)Is reason for not porting this for ARM was it is not good for detecting kernel memory corruption ?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no limitations for ARM architecture in `CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC` definition: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/Kconfig.debug. Probably, you have other options incompatible with it. In `make menuconfig` you can get info about this option (using '/' key) and check value for options it depends from.

Comment: I have tried it enabling this using make menuconfig, But it has dependency on config macro ARCH_SUPPORTS_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC  which is not defined for ARM.

Comment: Thank you Understood how to enable this for ARM :)

Comment: @PradeepGoswami It will be helpful if you post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implemented for ARM architecture. see [here](http://here)